# Управление кнопками Horizontal и Vertical / Unity Engine

Tags: unity3d, input, события, ui

У меня есть две UI кнопки. Я не хочу ими управлять мышкой, а хочу управлять ими стрелками или WASD, они подсвечиваются и по кнопке допустим Enter активировался ивент как на обычной кнопке. (Например как в главном меню Super Mario Bros)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В целом, такая функциональность уже реализована в Unity UI. Для того, чтобы это заработало у вас, нужно сделать пару действий:

1. Если вы хотите управлять UI с помощью клавиатуры (или геймпада, тут разницы нет) вам нужно, чтобы какой-то UI элемент имел начальный фокус. Если этого фокуса не будет, тогда все-равно придется пользоваться мышкой/касанием. Чтобы установить начальный фокус на какую-нибудь кнопку UI, вам нужно поработать с UI Event System.
   Сделать это можно 2 способами: либо кодом, либо в самом компоненте Event System на сцене. По поводу кода, можно сделать так: `EventSystem.current.SetSelectedGameObject()` (использование этого метода зависит от версии Unity - [документация для 2018.1](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.EventSystem.SetSelectedGameObject.html)). Чтобы указать выбранный объект в компоненте - выберите Event System на сцене (он создается вместе c Canvas)и перетащите нужную кнопку в поле "First Selected". Выглядит этот компонент примерно так: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. Затем вам нужно разобраться с навигацией по вашему UI, а в частности с перемещением фокуса при использовании стрелок на клавиатуре. На эту тему можно посмотреть [официальную документацию по навигации](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-SelectableNavigation.html). Это делается достаточно легко, вы выбираете кнопку на сцене и указываете для нее значение в поле Navigation компонента Button. По умолчанию будет стоять значение None. Выберите нужное вам значение. После этого вы можете посмотреть всю схему навигации на сцене нажав кнопку Visualize - на сцене переходы между фокусом объектов UI будут нарисованы желтыми стрелками. Например: 
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. Если вы хотите управлять навигацией на сцене с помощью каких-нибудь определенных кнопок - это также можно настроить. По умолчанию перемещение фокуса происходит по средствам стрелок на клавиатуре + wasd (указанных как альтернативные значения). Чтобы настроить свои значения - измените соответствующие настройки в Input Manager. Для этого откройте Edit->Project Settings->Input. Далее смотрите на значения Horizontal и Vertical в Axes. Для каждой из этих осей есть 4 поля настройки - Negative Button, Positive Button, Alt Negative Button, Alt Positive Button, в которые можно указывать нужные вам клавиши. Скрин для наглядности: 
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]